# Is it safe to use startActivityForResult() for sensitive data?

Tags: java, android, security

I'm looking into starting an Activity (different app) with some parameters (sensitive session) and was wondering what's the safest way here. For instance, startActivityForResult() may be used on Android and I was wondering if any other app can see this request or if it requires root rights to intercept such a request? So basically, is it safe to use it or not? By default, we assume users don't have root rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if any other app can see this request

The app that responds to your `startActivityForResult()` call can see the request. That could be:

- The real unmodified app that you wish to send the data to
- A hacked version of that app
- A completely independent app that happens to match your `Intent`, particularly if you are using an implicit `Intent`

You can try to check signatures to confirm whether the other app is indeed the real unmodified app, so you avoid the latter two scenarios.

On older versions of Android, the `Intent` would be visible to other apps as part of the data backing the overview screen (recent-tasks list). That was cleared up somewhere in the 4.x series IIRC.

Those are the only two attacks that I know of for non-rooted devices.